# Connecting MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008-r2

I need a little advise, I need to sync a DB that is currently on a Server 2008(SQL Server 2005) machine and I use Studio Express to connect to it. I need a way of syncing this DB to mysql that lives on a NAS on the same network:

Local:
DB Engine on server, named, server\sqlexpress and IP = 10.0.0.201

Target:
DB on NAS, named, CISCO-NAS and IP = 10.0.0.182

Will need for this to sync every few mins...

I really don't know how to start.

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't a database, I'm confused.

Comment: Not sure but I would go for trying to export data from SQL Server to MySQL, as I think SQLServer has more userfriendly procedures to eventually do so.